# Precedence of .__dict__ attribute between "type" and the other classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following simple Python code:

```
>>> class C:
...  class_level_var = 5
...
>>> C.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'class_level_var': 5, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of
'C' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'C' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> #trying to reassign C.__dict__:
... C.__dict__ = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects is not writable
>>>
```

Calling `__dict__` on `C` connects with `__dict__` of `type`, though `C` itself has a direct `__dict__` on it as is shown by the output above: "`'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>`". Notice the error message on assignment to `None` revealing that the attribute belongs to `type`, not `C`'s.

My question is: Shouldn't objects (class `C`) attributes take precedence over their class (class `type`) attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting the error message.

You think that the error message is referring to the attribute `type.__dict__`, but when it says

```
AttributeError: attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

it means that the `__dict__` attribute of *instances of `type`* is not writable. `C` itself is an instance of `type`, and its `__dict__` attribute is not writable.

You might also want to read about the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). Attribute lookup for the `__dict__` attribute of an object is managed by a descriptor for `__dict__` in the object's class or an ancestor class. Since `C` is an instance of `type`, lookup for `C.__dict__` is managed by a descriptor owned by `type`. This descriptor controls what happens when you read or (try to) write the attribute, and it's what says you can't assign `C.__dict__`.

The `'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>` entry you saw in `C.__dict__` is not `C.__dict__`; it's the descriptor that manages the `__dict__` attribute of instances of `C`.

Comment: I'm fully aware it's a descriptor. And the descriptor that (type.__dict__) is is what's evaluating here, not the one on class C. The error message is of general sense here.       "C itself is an instance of type" - I agree. "and its __dict__ attribute is not writable." - No, I don't think that's the one, it's referring to the one on "type", which translates differently across the different objects, i.e. the reason why a descriptor is used.

Comment: @Searcherer: `C`'s `__dict__` attribute is not writable, because the descriptor for `C.__dict__` (which is the descriptor in `type.__dict__`, not the descriptor in `C.__dict__`) says it's not writable. Are you expecting the descriptor in `C.__dict__` to be used for some reason? That's the wrong descriptor. The `'__dict__'` entry in `C.__dict__` is not `C`'s `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: Are you unaware of the rules for data descriptors? `__dict__` descriptors are data descriptors, and a data descriptor found when searching an object's class takes priority over anything found in the object's own dict. In this case, that means the descriptor found in `type.__dict__` takes priority over the `'__dict__'` entry in `C.__dict__` when looking up the `C.__dict__` attribute.

Comment: I should probably go take an in-depth look at descriptors before delving deeper into this  and wasting your time. .. will post back if needed. I appreciate your guidance (-: